# google spreadsheet line chart behavior changed on 11/28

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

[Google Spreadsheet Chart behavior changed on 11/28/2018](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OTxq.png)

See image in the link above. From yesterday 11/28, Y-axis of the line chart is showing data from zero by default, even though all of the value in the chart are in a positive range between min [180] and max [200] values. Earlier, the Y axis would smartly show just the range of data between the min and max values.

Can other confirm?

Google Spreadsheet team: can you please confirm this change in behavior? I have also filed a bug using "Help -> Report a problem" feature in google spreadsheets.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I noticed the same thing this morning. Charts in Sheets are no longer auto sizing according to the data. You can, of course, manually supply min and max values for your axes, but this is not ideal, as the axes no longer change automatically. Hopefully a bug that Google will fix (?).

Comment: I am creating the charts programatically using spreadsheet API V4. The API does not have any option to set the min and max values. In any case, the feature is broken, which Google should fix.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is still on at time of writing.

There's a discussion open on Google's Product Forum (https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/8Ygs6buY5rk) in which various tests with different OS and browser combinations are performed, to no avail (or, at least, partial joy: the same browsers tried by OP give correct output to some and wrong to others).

I tried on OSX (Chrome, Firefox, Safari) and Windows 7 (IE, Chrome, Firefox) and in no circumstance the chart displays as intended.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120157983

Please upvote the bug filed for this issue for Google to fix